# Npm install fails on heroku: error phantomjs@1.9.7-5 install: `node install.js

Tags: heroku, npm, phantomjs

npm install works when run on my local machine and on codeship.io, but fails on heroku.
This seems to be an issue with the phantom npm package. It has happened on two separate projects simultaneously. Both works locally, on codeship and on my deployment server, but wont run on heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Founder of [Codeship](http://codeship.io) here.

Have you tried setting the phantom npm package as a development dependency so it doesn't get installed on Heroku?